# WCF with SQL Database on azure. Which plan is best VM or (Database Service + Cloud Service)

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I want to create wcf web service with SQL Server database. I am confused which is azure best plan. Now i recommended 20GB database size. Please help me to select best plan Virtual machine or purchase separate Database Service and cloud service for wcf service.

There are two possibility.

1. Publish WCF Service on Azure Cloud Service And Database on Azure SQL Database.
2. Publish both WCF Service and SQL Database on Azure Virtual Machine.

   a. Install SQL Server on Azure VM and update database on it.

   b. Configure WCF Service on VM IIS.

Which is the best way consider performance and pricing?

Comment: This depends on something more than just the database size. Can you give some more information on what you're actually doing? Azure SQL DB and a SQL Server in an Azure VM have some (minor) differences. Also for the WCF service the size of the VM can vary depending on what you're doing with your service. In some cases it can also be better to run on Azure Web Sites. There are many things which influences this decision, so the more information you can give the better an appropriate plan can be chosen.

Comment: Based on performance, I would go with SQL Database because it is prepared for scalability /availability. With VM you can achieve the same, but it's up to you. The WCF I would go with Cloud Services.

Comment: I also would go with the suggestion made by @ThiagoCustodio. Depending on what you are doing with your WCF service I would deploy it to Azure Web Sites instead of a Cloud Service.

Answer (score 0):

using VM would give more flexibility to your system but the best option for you is the first option , the WCF service should published as a service cloud(web role or worker role depending on your architecture)
the SQL azure database would work just fine unless you're going to use multiple transactions which is not supported by Sql Azure database.
pricing wise the first option is cheaper since you're only using a service and a 250GB database which cost almost nothing